# URL # issuie c# querystring asp.net

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to sort out my querystring using the following. There is a hash sign that needs to be displayed in the address for example:

> Blk 344, Jurong West, Street 11, #02-111

Which is stored in the variable `address`. I am trying to use this code to replace the hash sign: `address.Replace("#","%23")`

```
string url = "thankyou.aspx?firstname=" + firstname + "&" + 
"lastname=" + lastname + "&" + "address=" +  address.Replace("#","%23")+ 
 "&" + "total=" + total + "&" + "nric=" + tbID.Text + "&" + "country=" + 
 ddlCountry.SelectedValue + "&" + "orderid=" + orderid + "&"+ 
"postalcode="+tbPostalCode.Text;
```

But it's still throwing an error. When I replace it in query string it is fine and the data is displayed fine, so this is not the issue.

Comment: methinks you need something like [HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I advice you to remove all those data from the url and use forms instread

Comment: Can you please post the exception that you get?

Comment: Why you are passing these number of data as Query string? You can try some other way like Sessions, storing in DB and and passing ID and get from DB from other Screen.

Comment: tried that on the address variable but did not work do i need  do it on complete url

Answer (score 0):

Use [Uri.EscapeDataString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx) to encode all query parameter values :

```
string url = "thankyou.aspx?firstname=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(firstname)
            + "&lastname="   + Uri.EscapeDataString(lastname)
            + "&address="    + Uri.EscapeDataString(address)
            + "&total="      + Uri.EscapeDataString(total)
            + "&nric="       + Uri.EscapeDataString(tbID.Text)
            + "&country="    + Uri.EscapeDataString(ddlCountry.SelectedValue)
            + "&orderid="    + Uri.EscapeDataString(orderid)
            + "&postalcode=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(tbPostalCode.Text);
```